Calculation of Current Capability of Copper Bus Bar

If we look the table 20x10 copper bus bar with 199 mm2 is able to carry 427A (bare bar)according to table.So we ended up with 2.14572864322 A/mm2. However, when we 30x10 mm2 copper bus bar with 299 mm2 is able to carry 573A, we ended up with 1,99 A/mm2. If we look 12x2 copper bus bar with 23.5 mm2, 108A / 23.5, we ended up with 4.5A/mm2.
In addition to this, on the internet as a rule of thumb, it says 1.2A per mm2.
So mm2 value differs for different size and we are not able to define exactly amp value for mm2. What is the reason of that ?

It's because a 30×10 busbar has a lower surface-area-to-cross-section ratio than 20×10 busbar, which has a lower ratio than a 12×2 busbar. The busbar's surface area is what determines how much heat it can radiate, while its cross-sectional area determines how much heat gets generated.
